# How to describe the total number of actions by a group of people?

Tags: word-choice

If Jack made 10 phones calls, we can write：
`Calls made by Jack: 10`

If the total phone calls made by everybody of a company is 1000, can we write:
`Calls made by the whole company: 1000` ?

I feel like that `the whole company` is not proper here but I can't say why and don't known how to say it.

Comment: Why not simply say "**total calls: 1000**"?

Comment: Yes I can, but I wonder the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**total**" is a fine word to use:

- Total calls: 1000
- Total amount of calls made by the entire company: 1000

Comment: What I am not sure is "the whole/entire company". I think the calls are made by people of the company, rather than the company itself?

Comment: PS: Is "entire" better than "whole" in this context? why?

Comment: @TimothyZhang When you say "*whole/entire company*" you refer to the people working there and not to the  building.